# Django file upload and creating directories

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to implement dropbox application using django.
I completed with user login,signup part . Also with with some authentications.

Now i want to implement file uploads , creating directories and sharing files with users. Also preview of uploaded files for respective user.

Right now i have extended user model for setting user. I have not written any model.

How should i proceed further? a new model is necessary for this application?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model that represents the file that you could upload, so you can save the url, the name, the date, and so on.

Comment: i have extended django user model for login and signup. Now need to implement file implement and sharing. so if i create new model for file , then how can i manage files of particular user..like if user xx uploaded files, then when again user xx logs in he should be able to see those files?

Comment: Then you should create the File model and associate the user model. Like this:
`class File(models.Model):
     file_name = models.CharField()
     file_url = models.CharField()
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
`
And if you want to search the files that are uploaded by an user:

`File.objects.filter(user=user)`